# Saving an MS Project Report to a file

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2010, reporting

Using MS Project 2010, if you click Project->Reports, you have a number of very useful reports, but it seems like the only thing you can do is print them.  Can you save them to a file?

Comment: Print to PDF.  That will work.

Comment: Do you want the saved file to be reused in some way other than just to view/print?

Answer (score 1):

This [Microsoft article - Export Project data to another file format](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/project-help/export-project-data-to-another-file-format-HP043007930.aspx?CTT=1) explains how to use the file->save as command to export Project data to another file format:

> 1. On the File menu, click Save As.
> 2. In the Save as type box, select the file format you want to export data to.
> 3. To export project data to a SQL Server or Oracle Server format, click ODBC, and then continue with step 5.
> 4. In the File name box, type a name for the exported file.
>      Click Save.
> 5. Follow the instructions in the Export Wizard to export the data you want into the proper fields of the destination file.

There's also some notes and FYI's that you may want to read as well.

Comment: Hi @Iam, it's customary to post more than just a link in an answer on PMSE. If the link were to break, your answer would be useless to future visitors with the same problem. I edited in the steps from the link and referred users to the link if they need additional information.

Answer (score 0):

You can always save it as PDF through  Export as PDF. After all your goal is to save the file as pdf.

Comment: Hi Diablo, welcome to PMSE! Could you please elaborate how the PDF export differs from a project print mentioned by the OP? I have the impression that 'exporting to PDF' and printing means pretty much the same...